# Convert InnerList from Vb to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, get, set

I am trying to convert some VB code to C#; however I'm having some trouble,

Here is my VB code:

```
 Default Public Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) As BiometrikBilgi
            Get
                Return MyBase.InnerList(index)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As BiometrikBilgi)
                MyBase.InnerList(index) = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

And I used a converter and here is the result:

C#

```
public BiometrikBilgi this[int index]
{
    get { return base.InnerList[index]; }
    set { base.InnerList[index] = value; }
```

However in get {} line compiler gives error it says ;

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'BiometrikBilgi'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: *How can I fix this issue?* no offense, but have you read the error message? It tells you that you're missing a cast from `object` to `BiometrikBilgi` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `base.InnerList[index]` is apparently an `object` type, but your property returns a `BiometrikBilgi`.

Try casting the value you're returning:

```
get { return (BiometrikBilgi)base.InnerList[index]; }
```